# Having random crashes in my IOS CoreData App

Tags: web-services, core-data, ios7

```
2014-08-28 06:36:13.822 Beasty[84765:60b] 10  UIKit                               0x0000000101316d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
2014-08-28 06:36:13.835 Beasty[84765:3207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'statement is still active'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102aef495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010076899e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreData                            0x0000000100d65021 -[NSSQLConnection prepareSQLStatement:] + 97
    3   CoreData                            0x0000000100d647ca -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] + 58
    4   CoreData                            0x0000000100d878ce -[NSSQLChannel selectRowsWithCachedStatement:] + 62
    5   CoreData                            0x0000000100d7ed0e newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 1118
    6   CoreData                            0x0000000100db9bc1 -[NSSQLCore newFetchedPKsForSourceID:andRelationship:] + 1825
    7   CoreData                            0x0000000100db9058 -[NSSQLCore newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 616
    8   CoreData                            0x0000000100db8c47 -[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:] + 551
    9   CoreData                            0x0000000100db8639 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willRead] + 217
    10  CoreData                            0x0000000100d89226 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet count] + 22
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b03f76 -[NSSet initWithSet:copyItems:] + 534
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b03d41 +[NSSet setWithSet:] + 49
    13  Beasty                              0x0000000100056118 +[BTYUtilities returnRecordDictionary:ServiceRequired:] + 2280
    14  Beasty                              0x0000000100063d70 -[BTYPostHTTPData SyncCoreDataToWS:completionBlock:serviceRequired:context:] + 288
    15  Beasty                              0x000000010004735f __36-[BTYSyncRemoteOperation UploadData]_block_invoke232 + 63
    16  Foundation                          0x000000010238163b -[NSBlockOperation main] + 75
    17  Foundation                          0x00000001023cfd34 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 623
    18  Foundation                          0x00000001023d1c0b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103bbd72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103babeab _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 174
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103bbd72d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103badb27 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 380
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103badd12 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000103f0aef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000103f0dfb9 start_wqthread + 13
)
```

I did not want to inundate anybody with too much information here. I am new to  iOS and still unsure what is relevant . I will share more information if anybody is interested . The app also updates to a REST backend using AFNETWORKING libraries

Comment: Have you checked out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9523867/1144203

Comment: @isim .yes but I dont believe that I am accessing the same object in different contexts or different threads . Is there anyway that I can track that down?